# Extract lines from file 2 that matches values on two columns with those on a different number of columns of file 1

Tags: awk, pattern-matching, match, multiple-columns, lines

I am trying to use awk to extract lines from a file2 that match values in $132 & $133 columns with those on  $1, $2 from file 1 and create an output with those lines from file 2 (with have a lot of columns compared with file 1).

File 1

```
1   6727802 TTC T 0/1 0/0 0/0
2   12887332 C  A 0/1 0/0 0/0
```

File 2 (it has a great number of columns and also a lot of lines, I only show you one of them)

```
1   6727803 6727804 TC  -   exonic  DNAJC11     frameshift deletion DNAJC11:NM_018198:exon4:c.343_344del:p.E115fs   exonic  ENSG00000007923     frameshift deletion ENSG00000007923:ENST00000377577:exon4:c.343_344del:p.E115fs,ENSG00000007923:ENST00000426784:exon4:c.343_344del:p.E115fs,ENSG00000007923:ENST00000294401:exon4:c.343_344del:p.E115fs,ENSG00000007923:ENST00000542246:exon4:c.229_230del:p.E77fs,ENSG00000007923:ENST00000451196:exon3:c.271_272del:p.E91fs,ENSG00000007923:ENST00000377573:exon3:c.73_74del:p.E25fs,ENSG00000007923:ENST00000349363:exon3:c.229_230del:p.E77fs   Score=562;lod=257       614827                      rs374290353                 224 0.0020                          0.0001  0.0001  0   0   0   0.0006  6.805e-05   0   0.0012  0.0010  0.0012  0.0012  0.0010  0.0003  0.0014  0.0019  0.0020  MU9804  GBM-US|1|268|0.00373,PRAD-US|1|256|0.00391,LGG-US|1|283|0.00353,CESC-US|1|194|0.00515,BRCA-US|1|955|0.00105,SKCM-US|1|335|0.00299,COAD-US|1|216|0.00463 ID=COSM426618,COSM426619;OCCURENCE=2(NS),1(large_intestine),1(breast) het   280660  129 1   6727802 rs374290353 TTC T   280660  PASS    1   0.164634    2   -0.246  0   1498874 0   -0.0829 59.33   0.452   1.04    -0.079  0.72    3.49    FS  0/1 113 12                      129 68  68,0,4158
```

I use the following awk code with success to extract lines from file 2 that match values in columns $1, $2 with those in $1, $2 of file 1

```
awk 'NR == FNR { a[$1, $2]++; next } a[$1, $2]' 'file1' 'file2' > file3
```

But now I need to extract all lines from file2 that match values of $132 (file2) = $1(file 1) and  $133(file2) = $2(file 1). I tried to change the code in different ways with no succes. I would appreciate your help, I am new with awk!

Comment: then don't you want: `awk 'NR == FNR { a[$1, $2]++; next } a[$132,$133]'`?

Comment: I tried this but I obtain only a line in my output file not all the lines that I expect to find and that match these values.

Comment: Reduce your problem to an example with 3 columns in file1 and 5 columns in file2. Solve that then just tweak the column numbers to match your real file. What Glenn showed is a reasonable approach, though `NR == FNR { a[$1, $2]; next } ($132,$133) in a` would use less memory.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. The problem was that there a lot of columns with white spaces on file 2 so I added:  -F '\t' to  separate with tabs and now it works perfectly.